# Xdebug laravel artisan commands

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, xdebug, laravel-artisan

I regularly use xdebug to debug applications, I've built a laravel application that takes an upload of a csv inserts the data to the database and the ids to a job queue.

I've written an artisan command to be run via cron to then do something with this data.

Xdebug works for accessing the site via the browser, but its not breaking on breakpoints when ran from cli.

I run php5-fpm. My files `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php/ini`
both contain the following settings:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so 
xdebug.remote_enable = 1 
xdebug.idekey = 'dev_docker' 
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 
xdebug.remote_connect_back = {{my host ip}} 
xdebug.remote_port = 9000 
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

I then run the artisan command

```
php artisan jobqueue::process --batch-size=10 --sleep=10
```

I know the command is running as ->info('text') is displayed in the terminal

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: This related question looks helpful to me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27936323/470749

Comment: Had the same problem, took me more than an hour to figure it out, here's a working solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947395/how-can-i-debug-a-php-cli-script-with-xdebug/61865143#61865143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [xdebug.remote_connect_back](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back) documentation it's using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get debugging host. I guess that in CLI you must use [xdebug.remote_host](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host) instead.

Comment: Hi Furgas, could you please see if you could answer this related one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711818/xdebug-of-laravel-dusk-in-netbeans-on-homestead

Answer (score 37):

Maybe this will help someone.

In short I had the same problem but I didn't have luck with accepted answer. My solution is to run this from the command line:

```
php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_autostart=on -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 artisan my:command
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Netbeans still just says "running" and didn't stop at the marked line.

Comment: You should add `dxdebug.remote_autostart=on`

Comment: Hi Boroboris, could you please see if you could answer this related one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711818/xdebug-of-laravel-dusk-in-netbeans-on-homestead

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. `xdebug.remote_autostart=on` was the one.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows (XAMPP) but I had to format the command with a space after each `-d` option for it to work: `php -d xdebug.remote_enable=1 -d xdebug.remote_autostart=on -d xdebug.remote_mode=req -d xdebug.remote_port=9001 -d xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 -f artisan my:command`

Comment: If using docker:
`-dxdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal`

Answer (score 13):

If you're using XDebug version 3, try:

```
php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal -dxdebug.client_port=9003 -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes artisan your:command
```

### Update 2023-08

I'm using xDebug v3.2.1, php v8.2. Add these lines to `xdebug.ini` file if you don't want to write those long command every time. `/etc/php/8.2/modes-available/xdebug.ini`

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

Comment: This was all I needed: php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes artisan my:command

Answer (score 3):

I got it working with remote_autostart=1 and setting the PHP_IDE_CONFIG environment variable to "serverName=localhost". localhost is the name of your server config in PHPStorm.
Now when I run php artisan I can break at the regular breakpoints.

Let me be more clear :)

If you've got xdebug working with PHPStorm and regular requests this is what you should do to get it working with command line php (artisan).

You have configured paths in PHPStorm so it knows which file it should show you with the breakpoints. These paths are configured under a server (Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Servers).

The name of this server should be the serverName value in the PHP_IDE_CONFIG environment variable.

Comment: finally! I was using the right xdebug config but xdebug always fail. The issue was I need to set the server config in phpstorm with the right port and xdebug is running.

Answer (score 3):

If you use vagrant, than you can create `artisandebug` shell file.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
HOST=10.0.2.2

# xdebug 3
php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes -dxdebug.client_host=$HOST -dxdebug.client_port=9003 artisan  "$@"

# xdebug < 3
# php -dxdebug.remote_autostart=on -dxdebug.remote_connect_back=off -dxdebug.remote_host=$HOST -dxdebug.client_port=9003 artisan  "$@"
```

Than make it executable and run command :

```sh
chmod +x artisandebug

./artisandebug some:command --there
```

Answer (score 0):

For profiling with xdebug 3.1.1 and docker

```
php 
-dxdebug.mode=profile 
-dxdebug.client_host=IP_SERVICE_WITH_PHP 
-dxdebug.client_port=XDEBUG_CLINT_PORT 
-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes 
-dxdebug.output_dir=/tmp 
artisan ARTISAN_COMMAND
```

Example

```
php -dxdebug.mode=profile -dxdebug.client_host=172.19.0.3 -dxdebug.client_port=9003 -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes -dxdebug.output_dir=/tmp artisan help
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_host=localhost -dxdebug.client_port=9003 -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes artisan ARTISAN_COMMAND
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to:

1. First start debugger
2. Run: php artisan tinker
3. Within tinker run: Artisan::call('your-command');