# Xdebug in VSCode does not stop on breakpoint for Laravel artisan commands from command line

Tags: command-line-interface, xdebug, laravel-artisan, vscode-debugger

I work on a Laravel 7 webapp on my local machine (MacOS Cathalina). For debugging I use VSCode, PHP Debug and Xdebug (3.0.4).

When I open a page in the browser in debug mode, the execution stops on the first line with a breakpoint as expected.

However, when I run a `php artisan` command from the terminal, the execution does not stop on the breakpoints at all. I know that the code runs as I can print out traces to the log.

I use the "Listen to XDebug" option in VSCODE and this used to work in the past and I'm not aware of changing anything.

I tried to add [all possible configs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564826/xdebug-laravel-artisan-commands) to my php.ini, but it did not help (after restarting my MAMP):

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1 
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

For reference here is my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "log": true 
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Output of /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/php --ini

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/conf/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Output of /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/php -m

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

Output of which php

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Output of /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/php artisan test:xdebug

```
__   __   _      _                 
\ \ / /  | |    | |                
 \ V / __| | ___| |__  _   _  __ _ 
  > < / _` |/ _ \ '_ \| | | |/ _` |
 / . \ (_| |  __/ |_) | |_| | (_| |
/_/ \_\__,_|\___|_.__/ \__,_|\__, |
                              __/ |
                             |___/ 

Version => 3.0.4
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

           Enabled Features<br/>(through 'xdebug.mode' setting)           
Feature => Enabled/Disabled
Development Aids => ✘ disabled
Coverage => ✘ disabled
GC Stats => ✘ disabled
Profiler => ✘ disabled
Step Debugger => ✔ enabled
Tracing => ✘ disabled

                              Diagnostic Log                              
[Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (19).
[Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (19).
[Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

                                   PHP                                   
                           Build Configuration                           
Version => 7.4.2
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
                                 Settings                                 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/conf
Loaded Configuration File => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/conf/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.mode => debug => debug
xdebug.start_with_request => yes => yes
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.log => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.log => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.idekey => VSCODE => VSCODE
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
```

Please let me know, if you have any hints on how to debug this problem, or what could cause such a behaviour.

Comment: If you use "Listen for Xdebug" config in VSCode and if those Xdebug settings are correct, then it should be working right now. If it does not work then most likely that your Xdebug config is not applicable to CLI environment and only to a web server. Do the following: 1) Run `php --ini` and show the output 2) Make some temp artisan command (e.g. `xdebug-test`) and place `xdebug_info();` in that command code. 3) Run that command in CLI (`php artisan xdebug-test`) and show the whole output -- need to see your LIVE/actual Xdebug settings for CLI environment.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for the hints above. php --ini does not really give me anything uselful from the project folder, I added this to the post. Do you want to see the output of phpinfo()? Which part? I also created temp artisan command, but xdebug_info() is not recognized as a function, so I get an error message. How should I make this run? Thanks!

Comment: This means that your PHP in terminal has no Xdebug configured in your OS-wide PHP. Try `php -m` -- do you see `xdebug` module listed there? What's the output for `which php` (or maybe it's `where php` -- I'm on Windows so not sure which one is a correct one on Mac)

Comment: Also try executing `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/php` (*I think* it will be the correct path, but not super sure). Does it work? If does -- try with `--ini` parameter and use that path instead of `php` in your `php artisan xdebug-test` command.

Comment: @LazyOne Changing the php path returned some useful info. Please also see the xdebug_info() result in the post. What do you read out of this?

Comment: I think I got it running: it seems that the problem was that ran the artisan command with the wrong php version and not with the one that xdebug was watching(?). If I run the command with the full path of my php installation, it stops on the breakpoint. I think this went wrong during a mac update, when I was "forced" to use a different shell and I might have missed some alias to the right php version... Feel free to add a solution, you really helped me to solve this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: *"it seems that the problem was that ran the artisan command with the wrong php version"* Correct. Your default/system wide PHP (that is used when you execute `php` in terminal) has NO Xdebug configured. *"and not with the one that xdebug was watching(?)"* Sorry, but it does not work like that. Xdebug is just another PHP module; you have to configure your PHP to use Xdebug module (extension). It just with MAMP it must be coming bundled and preconfigured.

Comment: *"If I run the command with the full path of my php installation, it stops on the breakpoint."* Correct as in this case you clearly use PHP that has Xdebug enabled and configured. *"I think this went wrong during a mac update"* Most likely yes. Look into `brew` to install/update your OS-wide PHP.

Comment: *"Feel free to add a solution, you really helped me to solve this. Thanks a lot!"* I suggest you post your own answer (you can accept it later) with all the steps. This will help others in a similar situation (a question with accepted answer is much more visible than a bunch of comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally with the help of @LazyOne I could figure this out.

The root cause of the problem was that due to a macOS update my terminal in VSCODE was replaced with a new terminal, zsh.

This terminal did not have the right php path/version configured, therefore when I ran the artisan commands from the command line, I run it with the default php version without Xdebug installed.

When I changed the path to the php version installed under my MAMP package, it just worked. To make this more convenient, I added an alias to the zsh configuration file pointing to the right php version.