# "-1" file created in app root directory when running php artisan

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug, laravel-artisan

I am running Laravel on Homestead, and whenever I run any `php artisan XXX` command, the file named `-1` is created in the root directory of the app.

Contents of the file are similar to these ones:

```
Log opened at 2017-12-22 13:54:00
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 10.0.2.2:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-12-22 13:54:00
```

I am 99% sure it is related some changes I made in my failed attempts to make XDebug breakpoints work with artisan commands. I have `export`ed some shell variables, as recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28856207/41715780) answer, but when I run `export -p` I don't see any of them.

Did anyone have a similar issue? What setting can be causing such behavior?

Comment: That's typical xdebug log -- xdebug saves his activity (debug attempt in your case). Check `xdebug.remote_log` option (your php.ini or whatever)

Comment: My xdebug.remote_log is set to: xdebug.remote_log=~/code/xdebug.log. My projects are under ~/code/PROJECT_NAME, and `-1` files are always created within the root directory of a project.

Comment: In such case I have no clue. I may only suggest this: write custom artisan command that will show the xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output (to see all current xdebug settings that are applied to current session) -- maybe it will be shown there...

Comment: Thank you for a good lead! Helped me a lot in finding the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of LazyOne, I found the answer:

It seems that paths in `.ini` file have to be absolute. So instead of:

`xdebug.remote_log=~/code/xdebug.log`

I had to set it to:

`xdebug.remote_log=/home/vagrant/code/xdebug.log`

and now it works as supposed to.